# Do not understand source of memory leak display in Valgrind

Tags: c, data-structures, valgrind, singly-linked-list

Having spent most of the day trying to build my own singly linked list program with CRUD operations I stumbled on some items and found the below program which I am using as a reference. Running valgrind on this program though it shows a memory leak and I don't understand how it is arising or how to get rid of it. It shows the following location:

```
==51957== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==51957==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck- 
amd64-linux.so)
==51957==    by 0x420959: insert_at_last (sllother.c:110)
==51957==    by 0x4218C6: create_linked_list (sllother.c:102)
==51957==    by 0x4206F7: main (sllother.c:35)

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct linked_list
{
    int number;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

typedef struct linked_list node;
node *head=NULL, *last=NULL;

void create_linked_list();
void print_linked_list();
void insert_at_last(int value);
void insert_at_first(int value);
void insert_after(int key, int value);
void delete_item(int value);
void search_item(int value);

int main()
{
    int key, value;

    //Create a linked list
    printf("Create Linked List\n");
    create_linked_list();
    print_linked_list();


    //Insert value at last position to existing Linked List
    printf("\nInsert new item at last\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    insert_at_last(value);
    print_linked_list();


    //Insert value at first position to existing Linked List
    printf("\nInsert new item at first\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    insert_at_first(value);
    print_linked_list();


    //Insert value after a defined value to existing Linked List
    printf("\nEnter a KEY (existing item of List), after that you want to insert a value\n");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    printf("\nInsert new item after %d KEY\n", key);
    scanf("%d", &value);
    insert_after(key, value);
    print_linked_list();


    //Search an item from Linked List
    printf("\nEnter an item to search it from List\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    search_item(value);


    //Delete value from List
    printf("\nEnter a value, which you want to delete from list\n");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    delete_item(value);
    print_linked_list();


    return 0;
}


/*
    User Defined Functions
*/
void create_linked_list()
{
    int val;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Input a number. (Enter -1 to exit)\n");

        scanf("%d", &val);

        if(val==-1)
            break;

        insert_at_last(val);
    }

}


void insert_at_last(int value)
{
    node *temp_node;
    temp_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp_node->number=value;
    temp_node->next=NULL;

    //For the 1st element
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp_node;
        last=temp_node;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next=temp_node;
        last=temp_node;
    }

}


void insert_at_first(int value)
{
    node *temp_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp_node->number=value;
    temp_node->next = head;

    head = temp_node;
}

void insert_after(int key, int value)
{
    node *myNode = head;
    int flag = 0;

    while(myNode!=NULL)
    {
        if(myNode->number==key)
        {
            node *newNode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            newNode->number = value;
            newNode->next = myNode->next;
            myNode->next = newNode;

            printf("%d is inserted after %d\n", value, key);

            flag = 1;

            break;
        }
        else
            myNode = myNode->next;
    }

    if(flag==0)
        printf("Key not found!\n");

}


void delete_item(int value)
{
    node *myNode = head, *previous=NULL;
    int flag = 0;

    while(myNode!=NULL)
    {
        if(myNode->number==value)
        {
            if(previous==NULL)
                head = myNode->next;
            else
                previous->next = myNode->next;

            printf("%d is deleted from list\n", value);

            flag = 1;
            break;
        }

        previous = myNode;
        myNode = myNode->next;
    }

    if(flag==0)
        printf("Key not found!\n");
}


void search_item(int value)
{
    node *searchNode = head;
    int flag = 0;

    while(searchNode!=NULL)
    {
        if(searchNode->number==value)
        {
            printf("%d is present in this list. Memory address is %d\n", value, searchNode);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
            searchNode = searchNode->next;
    }

    if(flag==0)
        printf("Item not found\n");

}


void print_linked_list()
{
    printf("\nYour full linked list is\n");

    node *myList;
    myList = head;

    while(myList!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", myList->number);

        myList = myList->next;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

I added in the following code just before Return zero in main() as the author had nothing in their code to free the memory.

```
// Free memory
node *ptr = head;
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    node *next = ptr->next;
    free(ptr);
    ptr = next;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the deletion code `void delete_item(int value)`. When the value is found, this function leaks the node being deleted:

```
void delete_item(int value) {
    node *myNode = head, *previous=NULL;
    int flag = 0;
    while(myNode!=NULL) {
        if(myNode->number==value) {
            if(previous==NULL)
                head = myNode->next;
            else
                previous->next = myNode->next;

            printf("%d is deleted from list\n", value);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        previous = myNode;
        myNode = myNode->next;
    }
    if(flag==0)
        printf("Key not found!\n");
}
```

As you can see, this function lacks a call to `free`. You can fix this problem by adding a call to `free(myNode)` before the `break`.

Comment: Thank you this fixed the memory leak! I'm still geting my head around pointers but I thought only memory stored on the heap using a function like malloc needed to be freed. We never malloc myNode? Does it require to be freed because the original node storing the value that was deleted was malloc'd but when it is broken from the linked list it is then not included in the free function call in main?

Comment: @Aza That's right, another function has allocated `myNode`, so once you "break it off" from the linked list, you need to `free` it. Note that it is very important to make sure that `head` and `last` remain consistent, even if you remove the last node. Your current code does not do that: `last` may remain "dangling" if `myNode` that you deleted happens to point to `last`.

Comment: Ok thanks again, I'm kind of kicking myself I did not get on here and ask sooner you have been a big help.